# OSError: ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'ole32'

Tags: python, soundcard

I am using soundcard library for experimenting the loopback. But the error occurred when run `import soundcard as sc`. And the error line is below.

`OSError: ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'ole32'`

Does anyone know the cause of this and also how to fix it?

I already delete the soundcard libaray and re-install. But it didn't be fixd.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your python version and OS ?

Comment: Hello!! Python 3.8.18 and I use windows.